# Snowflake Asynchronous File copy to Stage Table via Put

Tags: python, asynchronous, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put

When copying a file to stage table in Snowflake I am able to run synchronous query like

```
cur.execute(Sql)

Sql: put file:///hfs/home/mwj2/sample.json @ioo_gtx_stage OVERWRITE=True auto_compress=false
QueryStatus.SUCCESS
```

But If I use Asynchronous query like,

```
cur.execute(Sql,_no_results=True)
cur.execute_async(Sql)
```

I get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loadGTXdocumentToSnowflake.py", line 211, in <module>
    main()
  File "loadGTXdocumentToSnowflake.py", line 193, in main
    status,errMsg = LoadFileToSnowflake(SnowflakeConnectionParams,LoadSettings,SparkiiConnection,KafkaMessage)
  File "loadGTXdocumentToSnowflake.py", line 102, in LoadFileToSnowflake
    status,errMsg,QueryId = SnowflakeConnectObj.PutFile(cur,FileName,Stage,IsCompress)
  File "/hfs/home/mwj2/snowflake/SnowflakeConnection.py", line 121, in PutFile
    cur.execute(Sql,_no_results=True)
  File "/hfs/home/s_eglueint/python/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 686, in execute
    sf_file_transfer_agent.execute()
  File "/hfs/home/s_eglueint/python/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snowflake/connector/file_transfer_agent.py", line 350, in execute
    self._parse_command()
  File "/hfs/home/s_eglueint/python/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snowflake/connector/file_transfer_agent.py", line 1053, in _parse_command
    self._command_type = self._ret["data"]["command"]
KeyError: 'command'
```

Kindly assist. Thank You

Comment: Theoretically it should work, maybe enable [**debug**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#python) mode and see if there is any extra information?

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming to this a bit late but leaving an answer as it took a while for me to find it out myself.

According to a similar issue posted [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/1227), 'PUT' and 'GET' are "just not supported by execute_async()". This is not in the documentation as far as I can tell.